# C++ Exception is Caught Late, what may cause this?

Tags: c++, class, generics, exception, operator-overloading

I have the following code in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

int main(){
    mtm::Dimensions dim_1(2,3);
    try{
        const mtm::Matrix<int> mat_1 = mtm::Matrix<int>::Diagonal(2,1);
        mtm::Matrix<int> mat_2 = mtm::Matrix<int>::Diagonal(2,-1);
        std::cout<<(-mat_2)(1,1)<<(-mat_2)(2,2)<<std::endl;
    } catch(mtm::Matrix<int>::AccessIllegalElement& e){
        std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

while it's supposed to give me the following output:

```
Mtm matrix error: An attempt to access an illegal element
```

it returns the following: (notice 1 at the beginning)

```
1Mtm matrix error: An attempt to access an illegal element
```

Here is how I have implemented `operator<<` in `Matrix.h`:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Matrix<T> &matrix) {
    typename Matrix<T>::const_iterator it_begin = matrix.begin();
    typename Matrix<T>::const_iterator it_end = matrix.end();
    return printMatrix(os, it_begin, it_end, matrix.width());
}
```

while printMatrix() code is:

```
template<class ITERATOR_T>
std::ostream& printMatrix(std::ostream& os,ITERATOR_T begin,
                          ITERATOR_T end, unsigned int width){
    unsigned int row_counter=0;
    for (ITERATOR_T it= begin; it !=end; ++it) {
        if(row_counter==width){
            row_counter=0;
            os<< std::endl;
        }
        os <<*it<<" ";
        row_counter++;
    }
    os<< std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

What may cause this bug and how may I fix it?

Please let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: Why do you believe the exception is late? Isn't `std::cout<<(-mat_2)(1,1)` a valid expression, and wouldn't you expect that to be evaluated before the next part, i.e. `<<(-mat_2)(2,2)`, that throws the exception?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `std::cout << (-mat_2)(1,1) << (-mat_2)(2,2) << std::endl;` is no more than a shorthand way of writing a chain of function calls.

Prior to C++17, the order of the evaluation of the parameters of the separate functions in the statement is unspecified.

So on some platforms `(-mat_2)(1,1)` might raise the exception, and on others `(-mat_2)(2,2)` might raise it.

One solution prior to C++17 is to break up the `std::cout` into separate statements if you want to control the behaviour more tightly.

From C++17, the order *is* specified, and the exception must be thrown from `(-mat_2)(1,1)`.

Comment: so what should I do in my case to fix this if possible?

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that from c++17 the order is specified, and the exception must be thrown from `(-mat_2)(1,1)`.

Comment: @smith, one option you have is to start compiling to C++17.